# Why Android Studio shows error in default files

Tags: android, android-studio

just a small help, whenever I try to open a new project Android Studio is showing me error. This time even in the default files. It started when some of classes could not be referenced. How shall I fix it? Tried reinstalling Android Studio. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: How can I check if the settings like SDK and Gradle is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just sync your gradle. It's really simple!